# Regular expression to validate csv line that contains integer ranges in ascending order

Tags: regex

Let's say we have ranges

- <0,100>
- (100,1000>
- (1000,10000>
- (10000,infinity)

expressed as csv line as follows:

**0,100;100,1000;1000,10000;10000**

What is the regular expression which will validate that csv line contains integer ranges in ascending order?

Comment: Why do you want to use pure regex, as opposed to mathematical operators?

Comment: Regex is not meant to compare numbers, at all. I think you'd want to look for any other solution than to rely on a regex for this.

Comment: I think regex is a lousy choice here.  In Java, I would just split each line on semicolon, and then walk through the resulting array in order, checking to make sure that each number keeps increasing.

Comment: The reason I need to use regex is the way I receive input from the user, which is string csv line

Comment: Which language are you using? Nearly all of them have a CSV parser these days.

Comment: @PatrikMihalčin I still don't see why you can't use your language's operations to verify that string. What language are you using ?

Comment: While it may be *possible* to write a regex for this (only *maybe*), it would be a train wreck. You'll have to do it in code.

Comment: If there is a finite known set of ranges, it becomes merely inefficient and un-maintainable to check the input contains them in ascending order : you then just have to write a regex that checks for every possible combinations of them in ascending order. I believe the number of regex alternations you'd have to write would be equal to the Nth [triangular number](https://oeis.org/A000217), where N is the number of known ranges. This number grows very quickly, as for 11 known ranges you already have to write 66 alternations.

Comment: I use Java, I thought that there is elegant regular expression which would do the job. Thanks for showing me the right direction

Answer (score 1):

You really won't go far with a regex. Plus it's simple to do an algorithm to verify what you want.

For example, in Java :

```
public static boolean ascendingOrder(String csv) {
    String[] values = csv.split(",|\\;"); // Split on either "," or ";"
    for (int i = 1; i < values.length; i++) {
        int lastValue = Integer.parseInt(values[i-1]);
        int currentValue = Integer.parseInt(values[i]);
        if (i%2==0) { // If it's the lower bound, should be greater or equal than last higher bound
            if (lastValue > currentValue) return false;
        } else { // If it's the higher bound, ensure no empty interval
            if (lastValue >= currentValue) return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

This verifies that ranges are in increasing order and don't overlap.